# отправка результатов команды в скрипт php

Tags: php, bash, cron

Подскажите как можно направить вывод команды в скрипт php
сейчас пробую вот так но не чего не получается

```
cat log.txt > php -r "var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));"
```

или

```
ls > php -r "var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));"
```

у меня есть скрипт который шлет уведомления в vk я бы хотел сделать чтоб вывод любой команды из крона присылался мне в вк.

как перенаправить вывод из баша в скрипт php, и как его принять в скрипте

```
file_get_contents('php://input'))
```

так не получается.

Comment: stream_get_contents(STDIN)

Comment: ls > php -r "var_dump(stream_get_contents(STDIN));" 
ls: cannot access 'var_dump(stream_get_contents(STDIN));': No such file or directory

Comment: во-первых, не > а | а во-вторых под виндой вроде работать не будет

Comment: но я бы конечно не занимался этим оверинжиниризмом, а просто добавил mailto=свой@емейл в кронтаб и получал весь вывод по-простому на почту